# Why this tabbed page child isn't recognized?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, tabbed

I have this tabbed page with 3 childs, the two first childs are being recogonized but the child page "Conversas" isn't. Visual Studio says it was not found and ask me to check assembly references.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BatePapo;assembly=BatePapo"
             x:Class="BatePapo.MainPage" BarBackgroundColor="#FF4383" BarTextColor="WhiteSmoke">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:Listar Title="Online" />
        <local:Home Title="Definições" />
        <local:Conversas Title="Conversas" />
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

I checked the code behind files, and all of them are with the correct namespace and the xaml files are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BatePapo;assembly=BatePapo"
             x:Class="BatePapo.Conversas">
```

All the child pages are almost equal, the unique difference is only its name. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could this be a 'case-sensitive' problem? Please edit the question to include the /exact/ names of the child pages. Also please post the xaml for one of the two that are working correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why but now I tried clean the solution again and it started to work. I appreciate your attention.